# Zend_view->render() not rendering

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a cron job that is running through some cases and if there is an error it should send an e-mail.

My code for creating the view to the e-mails looks like this (it's in my model class):

```
$layout = new Zend_Layout();
$view = $layout->getView();

$view->case = $case;
$view->forms = $forms;
echo "One\n";

$view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/modules/case/views/scripts');
echo "Two\n";
$returnview = $view->render('index/print.phtml');
echo "Three (it never comes here)\n";
return $returnview;
```

It never comes to the Three (as it says) (it doesn't gives a error, it just looks like it exit() there).

Anyone know why it never gets there?
we are using Zend FrameWork 1.12

Comment: Not all errors will send you e-mail, if you're using standard php error handling, enable error log, display errors, display startup errors, error level for php-cli ini, it can be syntax error or exception silently catched

Comment: We have all errors displayed  and there aren't comming any errors, neither on console (runnd as a cronjob) or in the php log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are able to just render a view with `$view = new Zend_View();`  and the rest of the code can use this :)

Answer (score -1):

from docs they are setting the template like this [enter link description here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html)

```
   $returnview->setTemplate(APPLICATION_PATH 
.'/modules/case/views/scripts/index/print.phtml);
    return $returnview;
```

I think you are  are confused with zend version < 2.0

Make sure that your display_error setting is set properly to see the error message

since you are using zend f-1.12 you can simply use $this->render("view"); from controller
You can access the view object from any where using

```
$returnview = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
```

Comment: We are using zend framework 1.12, sorry about not saying that right away.

Comment: on your edit, since this isn't in a controller i can't do that :) this is made inside a model, there are called from a script "cron.php" there is runned from a cron job

Comment: why does a cron job requires a view!!?

Comment: the cron requires a view because it's sending a mail!

Comment: Why should $returnview = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer'); give me anything related to my view i created in my question?